# Upgrade R version 2.15.1 to 3.3 on Debian server (linux-gnu)

Tags: r, linux, server, debian

I'm in internship and I'm working on a Debian server
for my R's scripts.

However, the version installed on the server is really outdated (2.15.1)
and I think, it might be the reason of some errors I have with my scripts
(which work on my windows PC with R 3.3).

But I am totally a beginner with Linux and I'm stuck.

I know there is a tutorial (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/)
but it's a very specific vocabulary I don't understand completely + my inexperience with Linux servers make it hard to understand exactly what I have to do.

Is it possible to have more explanations on how to install R 3.3 on Debian
server ?

Here are the details from sessionInfo() of the server :

- R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
- Platform : i486-pc-linux-gnu (32 bit)

Comment: Do you have administrative rights on the server, or are you just a user?

Comment: I'm just an user but to upgrade I will be with my tutor so I will have the admin rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you install the '-dev' version of base R

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

and then as a regular user use R's `install.packages()` to install additional packages. This will result in an installation where R and it's base packages are accessible to all but owned by root (and therefore difficult for a regular user to update / mess up) and other packages belong to the regular user (and hence easy to update).

Some packages may have system dependencies, e.g., XML requires the libxml2 and libcurl libraries. The '-dev' version of these libraries also need to be installed, most easily via apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

It may be that your version of apt knows nothing about r-base / r-base-dev. You should then follow the section 'Installing R-devel or a release branch from svn' in the document you mention; skip over the instructions in the 'R-devel' section, and instead follow 'r-patched'.

Comment: I have finally understood the way to install 3.x R's version ... It was quite simple but no one told me that the server was a wheezy one so I just followed the official tutorial and it worked perfectly. (had some problems with old installed packages though)